# How to make my binary executable as cmdlet in PS using Powershell script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have a binary executable called `ruby.exe` located in

```
C://test//ruby.exe
```

How can I make it as cmdlet using powershell script such that in my powershell script, i can run ruby directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it to the PATH variable. Then directly call with with Ruby.exe:

```
$path = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path")
$path = $path + ";"C:\Test\Ruby"
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $path, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine )
$env:path = $env:path + "C:\test\ruby"
```

Comment: $env:path = $env:path + "C:\test\ruby"
this will enable you to use it in the same session, but it will not persist in other sessions so you will have to use the method in the answer to make it persist

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're after "Splatting".  The magic is in using the @ operator, which will pass a list of arguments (or a dictionary of arguments) to the underlying command.  $psBoundParameters contains the magic data being passed down in splatting.

```
function Invoke-Ruby(
    [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArgumnets=$True)][string[]]$Arguments
) { 
    c:\Test\Ruby.exe @Arguments
}
```

To read more about Splatting, check out this article on [Hey, Scripting Guy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/10/18/use-splatting-to-simplify-your-powershell-scripts.aspx)

And, instead of trying to harness ruby in PowerShell, you might want to just try using PowerShell as a web framework ([PowerShell Pipeworks](http://powershellpipeworks.com/))